# SMS read status change using Java SDK

Tags: java, sms, ringcentral

When we send any SMS we can get the SMS messages id in the response and I have noticed that in the response the status is always **read** by **default**:

```
"readStatus":"Read"
```

I am not sure why the default is read and what does it mean?

What are the way if I need to change the status into not read or unread ?

I went thorough Java SDK docs and example here:

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-java

But haven't found a way to do it there.

Can it be changed with `java SDK`?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 status: `Read, Unread`
When the SMS is send the `readStatus` is always "`Read`"

You can use the message store API to update the status of your message.
Check this API here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Message-Store/updateMessage

Every SMS message have a messageId and you need to use that messageId to update the readStatus.
eg:
PUT [https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store/](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/%7E/extension/%7E/message-store/)

You can change the status with this API. Also using SDK, you can change that.
Check the demo here in Java:
https://ringcentral-tutorials.github.io/sms-api-java-demo/?distinctId=1746f43bd51496-0f9334d92b97c8-f7b1332-144000-1746f43bd523ca#5

Comment: Can same be done with Python sdk? Any reference on Python?

Comment: You can find Python ref here: https://ringcentral-tutorials.github.io/sms-api-python-demo/?distinctId=1746f43bd51496-0f9334d92b97c8-f7b1332-144000-1746f43bd523ca#5